# Como hacer que una tabla hecha en php + sql no me traiga los datos múltiples veces?

Tags: php, jquery, sql

Hice una tabla que trae los datos de los usuarios mas sus alertas, el problema es que duplica la fila y se trae la otra alerta, lo que yo quiero es que ambas alertas salgan en la misma columna y no se parta en dos

Esta es la tabla de los tipos de alertas

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_tipo_alerta` (
  `id_tipoalerta` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `ec_tipo_alerta`
--

INSERT INTO `ec_tipo_alerta` (`id_tipoalerta`, `descripcion`) VALUES
(1, 'Alerta Administrativ'),
(2, 'Alerta Personal');
```

Esta es la tabla de las alertas en si

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_alerta` (
  `id_alerta` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_tipoalerta` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `ec_alerta`
--

INSERT INTO `ec_alerta` (`id_alerta`, `id_usuario`, `id_tipoalerta`, `descripcion`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'EEEEEE'),
(2, 1, 2, 'AAAAAA'),
(3, 3, 1, ''),
(4, 3, 2, ''),
(5, 4, 1, ''),
(6, 4, 2, ''),
(7, 5, 1, ''),
(8, 5, 2, ''),
(9, 6, 1, ''),
(10, 6, 2, '');
```

Este es el query que utilizo para hacer la tabla

```
public function getListClientesClase($datos){  

        $Id_clase = $datos["Id_clase"];

        $arreglo = array();

        require '../require/Conexion.php'; 

            $sql = "
            SELECT cc.id_clasecliente,us.primer_nombre, us.primer_apellido, us.cedula, tu.numero_telefono AS movil,
            us.id_usuario, cc.asistio, cc.cancelacion_tardia, cc.web, cc.lista_espera, cc.id_clasefinal,
            cc.id_paquetecliente, pc.cantidad_clases, pc.fecha_vencimiento, pp.nombre_paquete, aa.descripcion
            FROM ec_clientes_clases AS cc INNER JOIN ec_usuario AS us ON (cc.id_usuario = us.id_usuario)
            INNER JOIN ec_alerta AS aa ON (cc.id_usuario = aa.id_usuario)
            INNER JOIN ec_tipo_alerta AS ab ON (aa.id_tipoalerta = ab.id_tipoalerta)
            LEFT JOIN ec_paquete_cliente AS pc ON (cc.id_paquetecliente = pc.id_paquetecliente)
            LEFT JOIN ec_paquetes AS pp ON (pp.id_paquete = pc.id_paquete)
            INNER JOIN ec_telefonos_usuario AS tu ON (cc.id_usuario = tu.id_usuario)
            WHERE cc.id_clasefinal = '".$Id_clase."'
            AND tu.id_tipotelefono = 2
            GROUP BY aa.id_usuario
            ORDER BY cc.id_clasecliente ASC;
        ";


            $result = @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);// or die(mysqli_error($conn));

            if(!$result){ 

                return null;

            }

            $numeroFilas = mysqli_num_rows($result);


            if($numeroFilas <= 0){

                return null;    

            }else{
                while ($resultado=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                    $arreglo[]=$resultado;
                }

                return $arreglo;
            }

            mysqli_close ($mysqli);


    }
```

Este es el codigo de la tabla HTML

```
function cargarTablaParticipantes(){
            var Id_clase = $("#Id_clase").val();
            var fechaClase = document.getElementById('fechaClase').value;
            datos = { 
                "opcion"  : "clientesClase",
                "Id_clase":Id_clase    
            };

            $.ajax({
                url:'../controllers/clasesController.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: datos
            }).done(function(response){

                var data = JSON.parse(response).respuesta;
                var msj = JSON.parse(response).msj;
                var success = JSON.parse(response).success; 


                html=`
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>Alertas</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Nombre cliente</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Cédula</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Teléfono</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Paquete</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Fecha de vencimiento</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Clases Restantes</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Web</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Asistió</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Estado</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Acción</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>`;

                if(success){
                    var valores = eval(data);
                    for(i=0;i<valores.length;i++){

                        html+=`<tr>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            id="Lista_espera" 
                            name="Lista_espera" 
                            value="${valores[i]["lista_espera"]}" 
                            hidden
                        />
                        <input 
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="Id${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}"
                            name="Id"
                            value= "${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}" 
                            hidden
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="Id_paquetecliente${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}"
                            name="Id_paquetecliente"
                            value="${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]}"
                            hidden
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="Lista${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}"
                            name="Lista"
                            value="${valores[i]["lista_espera"]}"
                            hidden
                        />
                        <td><i id="iconoalerta2" class='fas fa-exclamation-circle' style='color:red' title="${valores[i]["descripcion"]} ${valores[i]["descripcion"]}"></i>
                        <i id="iconoalerta1" class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:yellow;" title="${valores[i]["descripcion"]} ${valores[i]["descripcion"]}"></i></td></td>
                        <td>${valores[i]["primer_nombre"]} ${valores[i]["primer_apellido"]}</td>
                        <td>${numeral(valores[i]["cedula"]).format('0,0')}</td>
                        <td>${valores[i]["movil"]}</td>
                        <td>${valores[i]["nombre_paquete"] || 'Clase Gratis'}</td>
                        <td>${moment(valores[i]["fecha_vencimiento"] || fechaClase,'YYYY-MM/DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</td>
                        <td>${valores[i]["cantidad_clases"] || 0}</td>
                        <td>${valores[i]["web"]}</td>`;
                        if(valores[i]["asistio"] == 'Si'){

                            html+=`
                            <td>
                                <div class="checkbox"><label style="padding-right: 30px;">
                                    <input 
                                    type="checkbox" 
                                    name="Asistencia" 
                                    id="Asistencia${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}" 
                                    value="${valores[i]["id_clasefinal"]}" 
                                    onclick="cambiarAsistencia(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]})"
                                    checked>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>`;

                        }else if (valores[i]["asistio"] =='No'){

                            html+=`
                            <td>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label style="padding-right: 30px;">
                                        <input 
                                        type="checkbox" 
                                        name="Asistencia" 
                                        id="Asistencia${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}" 
                                        value="${valores[i]["id_clasefinal"]}" 
                                        onclick="cambiarAsistencia(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]})">
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>`;
                        }

                        if(valores[i]["cancelacion_tardia"] == 'No' && valores[i]["lista_espera"] == 'No') {

                            html+=`
                            <td>Participante</td>
                            <td>
                                <i 
                                style="cursor:pointer;padding: 1px 3px"
                                onclick="cancelacionTemprana(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]},${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]},0,0)"
                                class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"
                                aria-hidden="true" 
                                title="Cancelacion Temprana">
                                </i>
                                <i 
                                style="cursor:pointer;padding: 1px 3px" 
                                onclick="cancelacionTardia(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]},${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]})" 
                                class="fa fa-calendar-times-o" 
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                title='Cancelacion Tardia'>
                                </i>
                            </td>`;

                        } else if (valores[i]["cancelacion_tardia"] == 'No' && valores[i]["lista_espera"] == 'Si') {

                            html+=`
                            <td>Lista de Espera</td>
                            <td>
                                <i 
                                style="cursor:pointer; padding: 1px 3px;"
                                onclick="añadirParticipantes(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]},${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]})"
                                class="fa fa-id-card-o"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                title="Añadir a Participantes">
                                </i>

                                <i 
                                style="cursor:pointer;padding: 1px 3px;"
                                onclick="cancelacionTemprana(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]},${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]},1,1)"
                                class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                title="Cancelacion Temprana">
                                </i>
                            </td>`;

                        }else if (valores[i]["cancelacion_tardia"] == 'Si') {

                            html+=`
                            <td>Cancelacion Tardia</td>
                            <td>
                                <i 
                                style="cursor:pointer;padding: 1px 3px;"
                                onclick="cancelacionTemprana(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]},${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]},1,0)"
                                class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                title="Cancelacion Temprana">
                                </i>
                            </td>`;

                        }


                        html+=`</tr>`;

                    }
                    html+="</tbody></table>"
                    $("#claseClientesTable").html(html);
                }else{
                    html+=`<tr><td colspan="11" align="center" >No se encontró ningún cliente en la clase</td></tr></tbody></table>`;
                $("#claseClientesTable").html(html);
                }
            });

        }
```

La tabla sale así. Me gustaria buscar la manera de que los iconos contengan una información diferente para que no se dupliquen ya que los usuarios tienen dos tipos de alertas, la personal y la administrativa

[image: Ok]

Edición: Necesito que la descripción de cada id_alerta de la tabla ec_alertas salga en una misma columna en la tabla HTML de function cargarTablaParticipantes(), no que salga una alerta diferente en cada fila y se me duplique el resto de la información como ven en la imagen

Edición: Logré arreglar el error de repetir la consulta mediante GROUP BY aa.id_usuario, pero ahora no trae la descripción correctamente, se trae la primera que consigue del usuario

Estas son las demás tablas

Las clases del cliente

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_clientes_clases` (
  `id_clasecliente` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_paquetecliente` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_clasefinal` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_creador` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `asistio` enum('Si','No') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `cancelacion_tardia` enum('Si','No') NOT NULL,
  `lista_espera` enum('Si','No') NOT NULL,
  `web` enum('Si','No') NOT NULL,
  `fecha_creacion` datetime NOT NULL,
  `operation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_upd` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_USER'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Los paquetes de clases que compro el cliente

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_paquete_cliente` (
  `id_paquetecliente` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_paquete` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_centro` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_estatus` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `id_creador` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_detallefactura` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_clases` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_total` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_compra` date NOT NULL,
  `fecha_activacion` date NOT NULL,
  `fecha_vencimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `tipo_compra` enum('Servicio','Producto') NOT NULL,
  `operation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_upd` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_USER'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Datos de los paquetes en si

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_paquetes` (
  `id_paquete` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_programa` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_estatus` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `id_servicio` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_categoria` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_subcategoria` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_paquete` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion_paquete` text NOT NULL,
  `fecha_creacion` date NOT NULL,
  `tipo_paquete` enum('Frecuencia','Cantidad') NOT NULL,
  `duracion_sesion` time NOT NULL,
  `operation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_upd` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `id_create_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_update_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Telefonos de los usuarios

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_telefonos_usuario` (
  `id_telefono` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_tipotelefono` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `numero_telefono` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `operation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_upd` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_USER'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Has probado ejecutando la consulta directamente a la base de datos? seria interesante saber si el resultado de la consulta ejecutada directamente en la base de datos satisface el requerimiento, partiendo de esa premisa puede identificar si necesitas hacer cambios en la capa de base de datos o de aplicacion. Saludos!

Comment: @JorgeBeltran Hace lo mismo si lo ejecuto dentro de la base de datos, pone una fila debajo de la otra. Lo que quiero es que ambas descripciones en ec_alerta salgan en la misma fila en la tabla en HTML

Comment: Si logro entender bien tu requerimiento lo que necesitas es agrupar los datos de la consulta utilizando un GROUP BY, paseate por esta web te ayudara mucho https://guru99.es/group-by/

Comment: No tiene ningun sentido dar una recompensa, y es una pena que lo hayas hecho. No hay una respuesta canonica a esta pregunta, tu problema es que esta mal tu consulta.

Comment: Entonces, como podría arreglar este query?

Comment: ¿ Podrías poner las demás tablas que están en la consulta para poder reproducirlo?

Comment: esa query tira resultados duplicados en la base de datos? si es asi, sobre lo que hay que trabajar es sobre eso, y no sobre tu tabla de salida o tu php.

Comment: Use Group by aa.id_usuario, pero ahora no se trae la segunda descripción. Se trae la primera que consigue. Ya no se duplica, pero no trae las descripciones bien que era la segunda parte del problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro si la consulta te funcionará, espero que si:

Consulta SQL:

```
SELECT 
cc.id_clasecliente, cc.asistio, cc.cancelacion_tardia, cc.web, cc.lista_espera, 
cc.id_clasefinal, cc.id_paquetecliente, 
us.primer_nombre, us.primer_apellido, us.cedula, us.id_usuario,
tu.numero_telefono AS movil, 
pc.cantidad_clases, pc.fecha_vencimiento, 
pp.nombre_paquete,
GROUP_CONCAT(aa.descripcion) as alertas
FROM ec_clientes_clases AS cc 
INNER JOIN ec_usuario AS us 
  ON cc.id_usuario = us.id_usuario
INNER JOIN ec_alerta AS aa 
  ON (cc.id_usuario = aa.id_usuario) 
INNER JOIN ec_tipo_alerta AS ab 
  ON aa.id_tipoalerta = ab.id_tipoalerta
LEFT JOIN ec_paquete_cliente AS pc 
  ON cc.id_paquetecliente = pc.id_paquetecliente
LEFT JOIN ec_paquetes AS pp
  ON pp.id_paquete = pc.id_paquete
INNER JOIN ec_telefonos_usuario AS tu 
  ON cc.id_usuario = tu.id_usuario
WHERE cc.id_clasefinal = 1 AND tu.id_tipotelefono = 1 
ORDER BY cc.id_clasecliente ASC;
```

Use la función GROUP_CONCAT (con el alias "alertas") que devuelve una string con los valores agrupados de la siguiente manera "EEEEEE,AAAAAA".

Ahora solo necesitas separar el campo con el alias "alertas" en el script JS de la siguiente manera.

```
function cargarTablaParticipantes() {
  var Id_clase = $("#Id_clase").val();
  var fechaClase = document.getElementById('fechaClase').value;
  datos = {
    "opcion": "clientesClase",
    "Id_clase": Id_clase
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: '../controllers/clasesController.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: datos
  }).done(function(response) {

    var data = JSON.parse(response).respuesta;
    var msj = JSON.parse(response).msj;
    var success = JSON.parse(response).success;


    html = `
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Alertas</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Nombre cliente</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Cédula</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Teléfono</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Paquete</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Fecha de vencimiento</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Clases Restantes</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Web</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Asistió</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Estado</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Acción</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>`;

    if (success) {
      var valores = eval(data);
      for (i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {

        let alerta = valores[i]["alertas"].split(',');

        html += `<tr>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        id="Lista_espera" 
                        name="Lista_espera" 
                        value="${valores[i]["lista_espera"]}" 
                        hidden
                    />
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="Id${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}"
                        name="Id"
                        value= "${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}" 
                        hidden
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="Id_paquetecliente${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}"
                        name="Id_paquetecliente"
                        value="${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]}"
                        hidden
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="Lista${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}"
                        name="Lista"
                        value="${valores[i]["lista_espera"]}"
                        hidden
                    />
                    <td><i id="iconoalerta2" class='fas fa-exclamation-circle' style='color:red' title="${alerta[0]} ${alerta[0]}"></i>
                    <i id="iconoalerta1" class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:yellow;" title="${alerta[1]} ${alerta[1]}"></i></td></td>
                    <td>${valores[i]["primer_nombre"]} ${valores[i]["primer_apellido"]}</td>
                    <td>${numeral(valores[i]["cedula"]).format('0,0')}</td>
                    <td>${valores[i]["movil"]}</td>
                    <td>${valores[i]["nombre_paquete"] || 'Clase Gratis'}</td>
                    <td>${moment(valores[i]["fecha_vencimiento"] || fechaClase,'YYYY-MM/DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</td>
                    <td>${valores[i]["cantidad_clases"] || 0}</td>
                    <td>${valores[i]["web"]}</td>`;
        if (valores[i]["asistio"] == 'Si') {

          html += `
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox"><label style="padding-right: 30px;">
                                <input 
                                type="checkbox" 
                                name="Asistencia" 
                                id="Asistencia${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}" 
                                value="${valores[i]["id_clasefinal"]}" 
                                onclick="cambiarAsistencia(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]})"
                                checked>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>`;

        } else if (valores[i]["asistio"] == 'No') {

          html += `
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label style="padding-right: 30px;">
                                    <input 
                                    type="checkbox" 
                                    name="Asistencia" 
                                    id="Asistencia${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}" 
                                    value="${valores[i]["id_clasefinal"]}" 
                                    onclick="cambiarAsistencia(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]})">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>`;
        }

        if (valores[i]["cancelacion_tardia"] == 'No' && valores[i]["lista_espera"] == 'No') {

          html += `
                        <td>Participante</td>
                        <td>
                            <i 
                            style="cursor:pointer;padding: 1px 3px"
                            onclick="cancelacionTemprana(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]},${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]},0,0)"
                            class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"
                            aria-hidden="true" 
                            title="Cancelacion Temprana">
                            </i>
                            <i 
                            style="cursor:pointer;padding: 1px 3px" 
                            onclick="cancelacionTardia(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]},${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]})" 
                            class="fa fa-calendar-times-o" 
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            title='Cancelacion Tardia'>
                            </i>
                        </td>`;

        } else if (valores[i]["cancelacion_tardia"] == 'No' && valores[i]["lista_espera"] == 'Si') {

          html += `
                        <td>Lista de Espera</td>
                        <td>
                            <i 
                            style="cursor:pointer; padding: 1px 3px;"
                            onclick="añadirParticipantes(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]},${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]})"
                            class="fa fa-id-card-o"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            title="Añadir a Participantes">
                            </i>

                            <i 
                            style="cursor:pointer;padding: 1px 3px;"
                            onclick="cancelacionTemprana(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]},${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]},1,1)"
                            class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            title="Cancelacion Temprana">
                            </i>
                        </td>`;

        } else if (valores[i]["cancelacion_tardia"] == 'Si') {

          html += `
                        <td>Cancelacion Tardia</td>
                        <td>
                            <i 
                            style="cursor:pointer;padding: 1px 3px;"
                            onclick="cancelacionTemprana(${valores[i]["id_usuario"]},${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]},1,0)"
                            class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            title="Cancelacion Temprana">
                            </i>
                        </td>`;

        }


        html += `</tr>`;

      }
      html += "</tbody></table>"
      $("#claseClientesTable").html(html);
    } else {
      html += `<tr><td colspan="11" align="center" >No se encontró ningún cliente en la clase</td></tr></tbody></table>`;
      $("#claseClientesTable").html(html);
    }
  });

}
```

Creé una variable en el script JS llamada "alerta" que separa el valor del campo "alertas" por comas (en el script está de ejemplo).

```
let alerta = valores[i]["alertas"].split(',');
```

Ahora que están separados los resultados los podemos añadir a las filas de la siguiente manera (en el script está de ejemplo).

```
<td><i id="iconoalerta2" class='fas fa-exclamation-circle' style='color:red' title="${alerta[0]} ${alerta[0]}"></i>
<i id="iconoalerta1" class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:yellow;" title="${alerta[1]} ${alerta[1]}"></i></td></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes separar las alertas desde SQL, y así juntar íconos independientes en una columna HTML.

En la consulta:

```
SELECT cc.id_clasecliente
       ...
     , group_concat( if(aa.id_tipoalerta=1,aa.descripcion,null) ) alerta1
     , group_concat( if(aa.id_tipoalerta=2,aa.descripcion,null) ) alerta2
  FROM ...
  GROUP BY aa.id_usuario
```

En javascript:

```
              html+=`<td>`;
              if(valores[i]["alerta2"] != null){
                  html+=`<i id="iconoalerta2" 
                            class='fas fa-exclamation-circle' 
                            style='color:red' 
                            title="${valores[i]["alerta2"]}>
                         </i>`;
              }
              if(valores[i]["alerta1"] != null){
                  html+=`<i id="iconoalerta1"  
                            class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" 
                            style="color:yellow;" 
                            title="${valores[i]["alerta1"]}>
                         </i>`;
              html+=`</td>`;
```

La tabla de alertas no tiene restricción para que un usuario sólo pueda tener un tipo de alerta; si el caso es válido tal vez necesites hacer ajustes.

Comment: Intente group_concat y PHPMYADMIN me dice que "La columna 'aa.tipo_alerta' en field list es desconocida"